# How one can protect a computer from the "Process Doppelgänging" attack and how to detect such an attack?

Tags: windows, security, anti-virus, vulnerabilities

A new code injection attack has been reported that is called "Process Doppelgänging." All versions of Windows are said to be vulnerable. The attack was found to be invisible to all major security products and is said to be unpatchable.

How one can detect such an attack and protect from it?

Comment: Use caution, common sense with your computer usage and habits!! Hope the researchers are working with the vendors to disclose the information rather than making it public to plug the vulnerability. Wonder if it's a process like `svchost.exe` and you can pass it parameters, etc. to inject malicious code. Without knowing the specifics of the vulnerability, it is hard to say how to stay secure rather than the basic 101 security practices. If there's a backdoor and the vendor knows about it with it's closed source code then you'll never beat those backdoors regardless really unless found.

Comment: if the major AVs can't find it, then you don't have much hope of doing so yourself. you will have to wait until they fix their products, or windows patches the underlying vulnerability in NTFS or in the Loader or both.

Answer (score 3):

#### How one can detect such an attack and protect from it?

Right now this attack vector is not detectable, until the various anti-whatever vendors upgrade their offerings and/or Microsoft issues patches.

So the only **certain** way to protect from this attack is to not connect to the internet.

You can, of course, take all the precautions that you should already be taking:

- Make sure that your OS and all anti-whatever programs are fully patched and definitions updated
- Don't open any attachments that you are not expecting or that have been sent by people you don't know or trust
- Only browse to trusted websites
- Ensure you have an adequate backup strategy
- Consider installing something like [Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/en-uk/products/deep-freeze) ("With Faronics Deep Freeze, you can cease to worry about any computer issues caused by visits to malicious sites, accidental changes or the like. When things go awry, simply reboot the machine and it will be returned to its initial pristine configuration.")

---

#### Process Doppelgänging

It has been reported that:

> Process Doppelgänging works on even the latest version of Windows 10,
>   except Windows 10 Redstone and Fall Creators Update, released earlier
>   this year.

The article goes on to say:

> But due to a different bug in Windows 10 Redstone and Fall Creators
>   Update, using Process Doppelgänging causes BSOD (blue screen of
>   death), which crashes users' computers.
>
> Ironically, the crash bug was patched by Microsoft in later updates,
>   allowing Process Doppelgänging to run on the latest versions of
>   Windows 10.

So depending on exactly what patches you have installed you may experience a BSOD instead of being vulnerable to the exploit.

Source [Process Doppelgänging: New Malware Evasion Technique Works On All Windows Versions](https://thehackernews.com/2017/12/malware-process-doppelganging.html)

> **The good news and the bad news**
>
> The good news is that "there are a lot of technical challenges" in
>   making Process Doppelgänging work, and attackers need to know "a lot
>   of undocumented details on process creation."
>
> The bad news is that the attack "cannot be patched since it exploits
>   fundamental features and the core design of the process loading
>   mechanism in Windows."

Source ["Process Doppelgänging" Attack Works on All Windows Versions](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/-process-doppelg-nging-attack-works-on-all-windows-versions/)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Lost in Transaction: Process 
  Doppelgänging](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-17/materials/eu-17-Liberman-Lost-In-Transaction-Process-Doppelganging.pdf) - PowerPoint presentation from the Black Hat Europe 2017 security conference

Comment: Unfortunately, those "good news" may be not so good, if the NSA or the CIA has already developed some malware installation kits that exploit this vulnerability, which could have been stolen by some malefactors, as it was in the case of the EternalBlue exploit. In such a case even a schoolkid could install malware on a remote computer, would not need to know any technical intricacies.